# Reusable jinja2 table

Tags: jinja2

I want to use the template to create all the tables of my project, but after writing is appearing errors like this:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
{{ table(headers={{headers}},items={{item}},url='None') }}
```

I've looked at the jinja2 website but couldn't find the answer to the syntax error.

```
# python 
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    context = {}
    qproducts = list(s.query(Product))
    context['products'] = qproducts
    return render_template('products.html', **context)

# table.html
{% macro table(headers,items,url,var) -%}
<table class='table table-sm table-dark'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {{headers}}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
    <tr onclick="window.location='{{url}}'">
      {{items}}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{%- endmacro %}


# products.html
{% from 'table.html' import table %}
{% block headers %}
<th>ID</th>
<th>Price</th>
{%endblock headers%}

{%block item%}
{%for item in products%}
<td>{{item.id}}<td><br>
<td>{{item.price}}<td><br>
{%endfor%}
{%endblock item%}

{{ table(headers={{headers}},items={{item}},url='None') }}
```

Comment: You don't need to surround variables with '{{' / '}}' inside  '{{' / '}}' blocks. You can refer it directly by the names: `{{ table(headers=headers,items=item,url='None') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you fix the references to variables (i. e. remove surrounding `{{`/`}}`) it won't work the way you expect. `block` tag can only be used with `extends` tag, but you use `import` for macros importing. If you want to write universal macro for table rendering it's better to use combination of `macro`/`call` tags:

```
{% macro table(headers,items,url,var) -%}
<table class='table table-sm table-dark'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {{ caller(mode='header') }}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
    <tr onclick="window.location='{{url}}'">
      {{ caller(mode='row', item) }}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{%- endmacro %}
```

`caller` here is a reference to a special function which invokes externally-provided callback. Then you can call this macro this way:

```
{% call(mode, items) table(headers=headers, items=item, url='None') %}
{% if mode='header' %}
<th>ID</th>
<th>Price</th>
{% else %}
{%for item in products%}
<td>{{item.id}}<td><br>
<td>{{item.price}}<td><br>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endcall %}
```

Every mention of `caller` in macro `table` invokes body of the `caller` tag with the specified parameters. So, you can customize the behavior of the macro.